# How to use a cell value for the folder name in index funtion used to extract values fromm another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have following formula in Z column "='\server\Project Details\Folder1\Folder2[Filename.xls]Sheet1'!$M$3"

I have folder names list in A column.

I want to make formula so as it will take text from A cell and use it as 'Folder1' in formula entered in Z cell.

Comment: You can concatenate text strings, through cell references, together either using `&` or using `CONCATENATE()` function. Use the first option.

Comment: Did mean you want to replace the folder  name "Folder1" in formula with text in Column A? If yes, you can try this formula: **=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(Z1),"Folder1",A1))**

Answer (score 0):

**This will solve the issue:**

[image]

**N.B.**

- `Row 1` has real path.
- Enter Folder's name in respective Cells in `Row 4.`
- Formula in Cell `Z8` to get the value.

`="C:"&X4&Y4&Z4&" "&[Test2A.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$352`

- In Cell `Z8` at last is `1`, which is cell value of `Sheet1'!$A$352`.

*Adjust Cell references & Folder's Name as needed.*